# Customize genmodel not to create plugin.xml, plugin.propeties and build.properties

Tags: eclipse-emf-ecore

I have a `metamodel.ecore` which I generate its **Model Code** from the `genmodel` file (Right click on `metamodel.genmodel` ==> Select *Generate Model Code*);

However, some additional files (`plugin.xml`, `plugin.properties` and `build.properties`) are created during code generation. Since I just need the model code for my special purpose (e.g. I don't want my current project to be converted to a plugin project), I want to prevent generating these files.

Any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

With the *properties* view opened, select the root element in your genmodel. You need to do the following changes in your genmodel:

- Set *All / Bundle Manifest* to `false`. It will prevent MANIFEST.MF to be generated.
- Set *Model / Model Plug-in ID* to empty string or use the button on the top right of the properties view named "Restore Default Value" to set it to `null`. It will prevent the generation of the files `plugin.xml`, `plugin.properties` and `build.properties`.
- Set *Template & Merge / Update Classpath* to `false`. This one is optional but with your use case, you may want EMF to stop messing out with your `.classpath` file.